# Solr: Multi Word Synonyms : Only first word is highlighting

Tags: solr, highlighting, synonym

I am doing index time synonym expansion for multi word synonyms.  In my synonyms.txt I have synonyms like (barc=>barc,bhabha atomic research center). But when I am searching for "barc" it is not highlighting "bhabha atomic research center". Only 1st word i.e "bhabha" is highlighting...

Can any one help me???

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now easiest way to fix this is to set LUCENE_33 instead of LUCENE_40 in solrconfig.xml and reindex. Highlighting will work then as expected.

A patch is now available: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3668