# Solr 5: only first word gets highlighted

Tags: solr, lucene

Search for: "test string"
Highlighting I get: **test** string

This has been reported as a bug and is allegedly fixed:
[Solr: Multi Word Synonyms : Only first word is highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616208/solr-multi-word-synonyms-only-first-word-is-highlighting)

However, here's my version of Lucene:
`<luceneMatchVersion>5.0.0</luceneMatchVersion>`

How is it possible that I'm still getting this behaviour?

EDIT:
There are no special settings related to highlighting in my solrconfig.xml
Here is the query I use:

```
hl=true
&hl.simple.pre=<em>
&hl.simple.post=</em>
&hl.fl=Comments,Summary
```

Comment: Are you using multi word synonyms?

Comment: Which highlighter are you using? There are 3. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting  Also can you post your solrconfig (if you have configured highlighting there, or the query you are using, and the complete results you are getting.

Comment: jay, you've pointed me to right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the application was incorrectly parsing tags returned by the highlighter - not Solr's fault at all!